# Problem with MaxStepSize

Tags: differential-equations

In the program 1 changing the step affects the solution where as in program 2 it is having no effects
Program-1

```
sol  = NDSolve[{x''[t] + x[t] == Exp[-1000 (t - \[Pi])^2], x[0] == 0, 
   x'[0] == 0}, x, {t, 0, 200}, MaxStepSize -> 0.8]
Plot[{{x[t]} /. sol}, {t, 0, 100}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions", 
 PlotRange -> Automatic, AxesLabel -> {"Time", " x"}, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, 13]]
```

Program-2

```
TFINAL = 100;
A = 0.0;
\[Omega] = 2/3;
Q = 10;

sol = NDSolve[{x''[t] + (1/Q)*x'[t] + Sin[x[t]] == A*Cos[\[Omega]*t], 
   x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 0}, x, {t, 0, TFINAL}, MaxStepSize -> 0.1]
Plot[{{x[t]} /. sol}, {t, 0, 50}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions", 
 PlotRange -> Automatic, AxesLabel -> {"Time", " x"}, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, 13]]
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: What is the problem? Is there something wrong with the solution you get?

Comment: for program 1 if I change the step size the solution changes but in case of program 2 changing step size has no effect in the solution , why it is so?